# Anaconda Python in Visual Studio Code PyQt5 import error

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I'm trying to use VSCode as my main IDE for Anaconda Custom Python 2.7.13 on MacOS High Sierra.  I'm trying to make a file open dialogue box appear using PyQt5.  In Spider the following works fine, but not in VS Code:

`from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
files = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()`

The error I get in the VSC console is simply `Not Available` whereas in the context of a larger program I get
`E1101:Module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' has no 'QFileDialog' member`.

I was wondering whether anyone had any idea where this issue is arising from?

Oli

Comment: sounds like youre trying to use a property that doesnt exist

Comment: @mast3rd3mon It does indeed!  But QFileDialog is an element of QtWidgets.  I am able to import the submodule with ```from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog``` but not use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran another QT5 program I was working on that I already knew worked in VSC and added a dialog box.  This worked fine, so I created a UI using QT Designer to add it to.  It seems that `QFileDialog` needs an instance of `class Ui_Frame()` to instantiate.  The fact that it worked in Spyder and not VSC may be related to the fact that the UI of Spyder is built on QT.